# Windbg help -> how can I read the code at this callstack?

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg

I have a dump of a windows service i made. The exception is that my code can't move a file (for some reason). Now, in my code there's a number of places where i move files around the filesystem. So, using Windbg, i'm trying to see the code where the exception occurs.

here's my !clrstack dump..

```
0:016> !clrstack -p
OS Thread Id: 0xdf8 (16)
Child-SP         RetAddr          Call Site
0000000019edea70 0000064278a15e4f System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
PARAMETERS:
    errorCode = <no data>
    maybeFullPath = <no data>

0000000019edead0 0000064280181ce5 System.IO.File.Move(System.String, System.String)
PARAMETERS:
    sourceFileName = <no data>
    destFileName = <no data>

0000000019edeb50 0000064280196532 MyClass.Foo.DoSomeStuffInHere(System.String)
PARAMETERS:
    this = 0x0000000000c30aa8
    filePathAndName = 0x0000000000d1aad0
```

now, this helps a lot...

```
0:016> !do 0x0000000000d1aad0
Name: System.String
MethodTable: 00000642784365e8
EEClass: 000006427803e4f0
Size: 88(0x58) bytes
(C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
String: C:\BlahBlahFolder\FooFolder\4469.jpg
Fields:
-snipped-
```

So i've figured out the file which failed to be moved. kewl. But i just want to see the code in this method MyClass.Foo.DoSomeStuffInHere(System.String) which calls File.Move(..).  That method has lots of File.Move .. so i could put try / catches / debug / trace information .. but i'm hoping to be more efficient by using Windbg to help find this problem.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the exact line of code, unless the application was deployed in debug mode.  And if that were the case, I believe it would be showing them in the !clrstack call.

Comment: thanks mate :) it's in release mode. I didn't want to say that because i didn't want to influence any answers, in case that was not the answer.

sweet dude. i'll try and rebuild in debug mode, release etc. 

cheers mate (and i was afraid that someone would say that was the prob).

cheers!

Comment: np.  you can also just refactor it so that the many calls to File.Move are in different methods...

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult problem and may require stepping outside of one's comfort zone of managed only debugging.

What you want to do is map the IL for the function **MyClass.Foo.DoSomeStuffInHere** to the dissassembly of that function.  My example below is x86 however x64 can follow the same steps.

This is referenced way down deep in the following link.
[Debugging Unexpected Process Termination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954593.aspx)

Example text from the whitepaper:
In the managed stack, **Debugging.Unexpected.btnSTA_Click** ...
Look at the code in the Debugging.Unexpected.btnSTA_Click event.

```
private void btnSTA_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   DebuggingCOMLib.STAClass staobj =  new DebuggingCOMLib.STAClass();
   staobj.RaiseError(1,5);
   Label1.Text += "STA Call Completed sucessfully";
}
```

If the source code is not available, you can examine the assembly by supplying the instruction pointer for the call-stack frame to the **!u command**. The instruction pointer can be retrieved from the !clrstack: output.

```
0096f970  03a00e06 [DEFAULT] [hasThis] Void
Debugging.Unexpected.btnSTA_Click(Object,Class System.EventArgs)
```

To disassemble this function, type **!u 03a00e06**.

```
    0:010> !u 03a00e06 
    Normal JIT generated code
    [DEFAULT] [hasThis] Void Debugging.Unexpected.btnSTA_Click(Object,Class 
    System.EventArgs)
    Begin 03a00de0, size 54
   <snip>
    03a00e18 8b15a89c1702     mov     edx,[02179ca8] ("STA Call Completed 
    sucessfully")
    03a00e1e e83d3590ff       call    03304360 (System.String.Concat)
    <snip>
    03a00e2f 5e               pop     esi
    03a00e30 5f               pop     edi
    03a00e31 c20400           ret     0x4
```

**Ok, now what?**
Scan your own !u output for a line like

```
call    03304360 (System.IO.File.Move)
```

Also, you can run !ip2md **03a00e06** to get the MethodDesc and then run **!dumpil**  to examine the IL code if that is easier.

You could count the number of calls to **System.IO.File.Move** in the **!u output** and then count down the same number in the IL.  Then you can use .NET Reflector to Disassemble the method and map the C# to IL and compare the result.

Lot's of steps, but it would get you to the same result :-)

Thanks,
Aaron